# Changing Activity ordering in Merged Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I have a manifest defined for a build variant package (debug) which includes a Launcher Activity, and then in my main manifest i have another Launcher defined. Now, in the Merged Manifest, because build variant is the highest priority, the activity from that manifest is first, which is causing issues when launching the app automatically, as it doesn't open the correct screen.

Is there any way to change the ordering of the activities?

Debug variant Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="FlagsActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="Debug Opts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity=".Debug"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Main Manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.launcher.LauncherActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
    [...]
```

Merged result:

```
 <activity
            android:name="FlagsActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="Debug Opts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity=".Debug"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LauncherActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
    [...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Debug variant Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.launcher.LauncherActivity" /> <!-- Put the activity in the order you want -->

<activity
    android:name="FlagsActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:label="Debug Opts"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:taskAffinity=".Debug"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Main Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.launcher.LauncherActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    tools:node="merge">  <!-- Add a merge here -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#node_markers